# Mongoose not saving record after array is updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've seen a couple similar posts, but I can't get anything to work. The following is for a podcast episode topic suggestion app. It's meant to upvote a topic by adding a user ID to an array of user IDs saved to the topic object. Everything seems like it works, but topic.save() isn't actually saving.

```
router.post('/upvote/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try{
        var topic = await Topic.findById(req.params.id);

        const reqId = req.body._id;
        if(topic.upvotes.includes(reqId)){
            res.status(409).send('Topic already upvoted.');
        }

        console.log(`pre-update: ${topic}`);

        topic.set({
            upvotes: topic.upvotes.push(reqId)
        });

        console.log(`post-update: ${topic}`);

        try{
            //topic.markModified('topic.upvotes');
            topic = await topic.save();
            res.status(201).send(topic);
        } catch{
            next();
        };
    } catch{
        res.status(404).send('Topic with given ID not found.');
    };
});
```

I tried a few different variations on topic.markModified() because I saw that suggested on other posts, but nothing worked.
Here's what those two console.log()s show:

```
pre-update: {
  upvotes: [],
  _id: 612d701dd6bbfd3c5c36c906,
  name: 'a topic',
  description: 'is described',
  category: 61217a75f30c6c826af9076b,
  __v: 0
}
post-update: {
  upvotes: [ 612996b46f21d2086c9d4d52 ],
  _id: 612d701dd6bbfd3c5c36c906,
  name: 'a topic',
  description: 'is described',
  category: 61217a75f30c6c826af9076b,
  __v: 0
}
```

These look like it should work perfectly.

The 404 response at the very end is what's actually getting sent when I try this. I'm using express-async-errors & if the next() in the nested catch block was getting called, it would send 500.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I think mongoose doesn't like it if you try to push() a new element like a normal array.

I used addToSet() instead and it worked.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-addToSet

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure what exactly your trying to do. If you want to add a new value to a field only at a particular place then `put` or `patch` is to be used not `post`. `post` will update the whole document. and `patch` `put` is for partial updation.

Can you refer the sample code which I have given, hope that would be helpful for you in one or the other way.

```
router.put("/:id", [auth, validateObjectId], async (req, res) => {
const { error } = validateMovie(req.body);
if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}

let genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
console.log(genre);
if (!genre) {
    return res.status(400).send("No genre found with given id");
}

let movieDetails = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
        title: req.body.title,
        numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
        dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
        liked: req.body.liked,
        genre: {
            _id: genre.id,
            name: genre.name,
        },
    }, //when using patch method, then you need not have to write this whole thing. instead just write req.body
    { new: true }
);

if (!movieDetails) {
    return res.status(404).send("No such movie details found.");
}

res.send(movieDetails);
});
```

Comment: Both put and post will execute whatever code you give them. I appreciate your trying to help though.

Comment: put is like editing data. post is something you are adding new data

Comment: Router.put() or router.post() defines what type of request you're listening for, not what the route is actually going to do. In the example you give above, findByIdAndUpdate is what's actually updating the database. Router.put is just saying that the code will execute when a put request is sent to that endpoint. You could have a put request that deletes data if you really wanted to and it would still work.